# Javascript : How to get multiple span elements by ID?

Tags: javascript, html

I have several span elements which begin with the same id as shown below...

```
<span id="graph_machine" 
<span id="graph_human" 
<span id="graph_custom"
```

I would like to access these 3 Span elements as an array in my Javascript function..

var elems =  document.getElementsById("graph*");

But getElementsById does not support returning multiple values. Any suggestions? Perhaps using a different function and some wildcard?

Thanks.

Comment: With regular JavaSCript this may not be possible. With jQuery this is easy.

Comment: @JohnConde If something not possible with JavaScript, it's even more is not possible with jQuery.

Answer (score 9):

Use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll):

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll("[id^=graph]");
```

That will return a node list of any element with an `id` attribute whose value starts with "graph".

Comment: @Givi - thanks for edit. Copy/paste failure there :)

Comment: This is way [faster](http://jsperf.com/elements-from-partial-id-comparison) than my answer. Use this.

Answer (score 0):

You could get all spans and then check each ID individually:

```
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
var graphSpans = [];
for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
    if (spans[i].id.substring(0,5) === "graph") {
        graphSpans.push(spans[i]);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Sp6sp/

Answer (score 0):

Try to get all span ID and then check if span ID starts with "graph"

```
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
var graphSpans = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i <= spans.length; i++) {
   if (spans.id.startsWith("graph")) {
      graphSpans.push(spans[i]);
   }
}
```

Since startsWith method is not available in Javascript, so you need to add it to prototype as soon document is ready.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
if (typeof String.prototype.startsWith != 'function') {
     // see below for better implementation!
        String.prototype.startsWith = function (str){
            return this.indexOf(str) == 0;
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery you can use `$( "span[id^='graph_']" )`

Answer (score -2):

try this with jquery

```
$("span").each(function(){
console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Demo
   http://jsfiddle.net/p5k2a/1/

Comment: (a) there is no mention of jQuery anywhere in the question (b) even if there was, this does nothing like what the question asks